# Python: better to make new temporary list or make multiple index accesses to same list?

Tags: python, list

I have a 3d list, and I need to compare each element at the lowest level to the max of the list it's in.

```
if lst[i][j][k] ==  max(lst[i][j]): ...
```

is this bad practice? it's worse on performance, the only alternative I can think of is

```
templst = lst[i][j]
if templst[k] == max(templst): ...
```

but this is worse on memory afaik.

Comment: I don't actually see any problem with the performance there.
Only problem could be that you compute max() everytime you conpare something to it.
Accessing List-Elements is actually quite fast, because it's just an array on the inside.

Answer (score 2):

> but this is worse on memory afaik

I think you assume that the new variable is a copy of the list, but it isn't. When you do `templst = lst[i][j]`, the only additional memory used is for a reference to the existing list.